# C# fahrenheit to celsius

Tags: c#, .net

```
  public static void Main()
  {
      WriteLine("Farenheit Here>>");
      int F = Int32.Parse(ReadLine());

      Double FtoC = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32);
      WriteLine("the celsius is {0} ", FtoC);
  }
```

The input works for whole numbers but I also want it to work for Decimal numbers. Ex. If I were to type in 10 it will give me an answer, but if I were to type in 10.5 it will stop working. I am indeed new to C#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use the number parser you want, currently you are using int

```
Int32.Parse(ReadLine());
```

You can use double, or decimal  (I'd suggest using decimal over double)

```
decimal F = Decimal.Parse(ReadLine());
```

then change to

```
decimal FtoC = (5.0M / 9.0M) * (F - 32M);
WriteLine("the celsius is {0} ", FtoC)
```

(the M is used to define decimal literals)

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

`int` does not store decimal number. Use `double` or `decimal`

```
public static void Main()
{
    WriteLine("Farenheit Here>>");
    double F = double.Parse(ReadLine());
    Double FtoC = (5.0 / 9.0) * (F - 32);
    WriteLine("the celsius is {0} ", FtoC);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm beginning to understand this a bit better now.

Answer (score 0):

Well, `Int32` is *specifically* for handling integers. If you want to handle `Decimal` values, they have their *own* `Parse` method so I'd be looking at something like:

```
public static void Main() {
    Console.Write("Farenheit Here>> ");
    Decimal F = Decimal.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Decimal FtoC = (5.0M / 9.0M) * (F - 32M);
    Console.WriteLine("The celsius is {0} ", FtoC);
}
```

And note the use of the `M` suffix. If you want to use `Decimal` types, you're probably better off committing fully to them, rather than reverting to the `double` type with all its [foibles](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bdouble%5D%20precision).